# Facebook oauth2 authentication failure: could not obtain access token

Tags: facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I downloaded the code from [Spring Boot and Oauth2 tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/), it ran well on my localhost. When I switched to my Facebook app id and secret, it did not work anymore. I suspect it's caused by my incorrect Facebook configuration, but could also be other issues I am unaware of. This is what I did: after test-running the original app on my localhost,

1. I configured a Facebook app with this Client Oauth setting:
   [image]
2. then modified the downloaded app by replacing clientId & clientSecret in application.yml [image]

   with App ID & App Secret from the Facebook dashboard. Everything else remained the same.[image: clientId and clientSecret].

When I ran the modified code (also on localhost), it successfully prompted for user credential, then produced this exception:

```
08:38:34.114 DEBUG 83568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] g.c.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider : Encoding and sending form: {grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[AQCw8wOC65ARKbwhtq8RWCL6LmohOP0txLcmF9wBDCOeAf34NenkoQ4Y9P9qIBpPOzJuWW10mnO62O15yladOvzprgApxZcHKUZ4byTKS5wvXiefYvkxJx6FBsKH421qsJowWHBX7Mu7HPSwLI-ShytKKgwlJlVHUX4EjIcmYHMdb31LLGh6rZxxadGP4y4fFHzuHGRc96mTfH2rsmoAQ3vVKqYp__MVdgd6ybX64EeRLEOPLIjMmYAZpbgZIx4ts1i65tY5u84Ny1CZkjJTaxS8lt4O2d-pLQ9Rh9oKESP64fRWmeNiP6-ibK2HSNKPy_sAHFrDJWMHazw8iUOll7jM], redirect_uri=[http://localhost:8080/login/facebook], client_id=[CLIENT_ID REMOVED], client_secret=[CLIENT SECRET REMOVED]}
2018-03-28 08:38:34.449 DEBUG 83568 --- [io-8080-exec-10] uth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:107) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Access token denied.
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:142) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:?]
... 60 more

more error messages removed to evade size limit.
```

Comment: _"Everything else remained the same"_ - and in case of the field from the first screenshot that contained a `localhost` URL, that seemed like a good idea because ...?

Comment: Just to clarify: I was still running the app on my localhost when I encountered the error reported above.

Comment: Well then please don’t show screenshots that show totally different app domain settings at the same time ...

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I registered a new application at https://developer.facebook.com with the same configuration. When I used the new APP ID and Secret, all went through without any problem.

I suspect that the APP ID and Secret I used earlier was too old (registered 3.5 years ago).